# Use command other than \item to render lists in LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am trying to come up with a template for [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) package. I would like to be able to render org-mode lists using `\cvitem` for example.  Better yet, if I could choose the LaTeX command for rendering list items (there are several available in this package).  I know about `:environment` and `:options` but these don't really help.  I would really prefer to make this as much independent of the export back-end as possible, so that it would be less painful to export the same document as HTML if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An export filter (section [12.15](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html#Advanced-configuration) of org documentation) can do that:

```el
(defun my-latex-item (text backend info)
  "Replace \\item with \\cvitem."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (concat "\\cvitem" (substring text 5))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-item-functions
         'my-latex-item)
```

For extending with other back-ends the `when` can be replaced by a `cond`.